# SQL count record by date group by product id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter, I face the problem when I `COUNT` total quantity `FROM wo_tbl_sales_items WHERE pdate GROUP BY pid`. query not given the corrected result, I show my code below,

```
$this->db->select("
        IFNULL(FORMAT(SUM(`si`.`item_total`),2), '0.00') as total_items_amount,
        IFNULL(COUNT(`si`.`item_qty`), 0) as total_items_count

    ");
    $this->db->where('si.pdate =', $date);
    $this->db->from('wo_tbl_sales_items si');
    $this->db->group_by('si.pid');
    $this->db->order_by('total_items_count', 'DESC');
    $result = $this->db->get();
    if($result->num_rows() > 0)
    {

        foreach($result->result() as $row){

           $data['parts'][] = array(
                'total_items_amount' => $row->total_items_amount,
                'total_items_count' => $row->total_items_count
            ); 
        }

    }
```

Also I show my database table structure,

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| mainid |   pid  |   item_name   |  item_qty  | item_total  |    pdate    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1    |   164  |   Iphone 6s   |     2      |   2000      |  2018-07-21 |
|   2    |   164  |   Iphone 6s   |     1      |   1000      |  2018-07-21 |
|   3    |   164  |   Iphone 6s   |     1      |   1000      |  2018-07-21 |
|   4    |   165  |   Samsung A6  |     1      |   600       |  2018-07-21 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I look result like this, please see below structure.

```
-------------------------------------------------
|  Items Name    |    Qty   |  Total Amount     |
-------------------------------------------------
|   Iphone 6s    |     4    |      4000         |
|   Samsung A6   |     1    |       600         |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your expected output, you need to `sum` item_qty not count item_qty

```
$this->db->select("
        IFNULL(FORMAT(SUM(`si`.`item_total`),2), '0.00') as total_items_amount,
        IFNULL(SUM(`si`.`item_qty`), 0) as total_items_count

");
```

Plain sql would look like

```
select si.pid,
si.item_name,
ifnull(sum(`si`.`item_qty`), 0) as total_items_count,
ifnull(format(sum(`si`.`item_total`),2), '0.00') as total_items_amount
from wo_tbl_sales_items si
where si.pdate = '2018-07-21' 
group by si.pid,si.item_name
order by total_items_count DESC
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70b390/6)

Try to move the formatting part (FORMAT(....)) from query to your application code.

Comment: same error, `item_qty` multiplying with some amount, than record not giving correct.

Comment: @MrTom I have tested the plain sql using http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70b390/6 and  there is no issue have a look